# Как подставить знак плюс «+» в поле <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы в поле `<input type="number">` отображался не только знак минус (-) при отрицательных значениях, но и плюс (+) при положительных.

Назначение с помощью JS значений типа `+1`, `+2` и так далее, вызывает ошибку:

*(цитата из Chrome)*

> The specified value "+1" is not a valid number.
>
> The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Как можно это реализовать?

Конечно же, при этом, функционал поля (изменение значения с помощью кнопок-бегунков) должен оставаться.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, создать второй `input` (текстовый) и в него дублировать значение `<input type="number">`. Предварительно проверяя на `+/-` (если число положительное, то добавлять к нему `+`)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
  fake = document.getElementById("fake");

input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  if(Math.sign(input.value) == 1){
      fake.value = "+" + input.value;
      } else {
       fake.value = input.value;
      }
}, false);
```

```css
#input {
  color: #fff;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fake">
<input type="number" id="input">
```

Comment: Как идея имеет место быть, я похожую прорабатывал, но тогда нужно добавлять проверку на то, что вводится вручную, так как можно ввести и буквы, а для `<input type="number">` такая проверка вшита в браузер. Ну и прочие мелочи, например, нужно по фокусу в текстовом поле активировать видимость кнопок-бегунков числового поля; так как посетитель может и не догадаться для чего этот белый прямоугольник справа :).

Comment: @w3lifer да. есть такое. Тогда наверно самое правильное будет отказаться от `type="number"` и делать свои кнопки `+/-` (стилизовать к тому-же станет проще). Откидывать лишние символы при вводе примерно так: `this.value.replace (/[^0-9+-]/, '')` и вешать на клик по `+/-` прибавление и вычитание соответственно.

Comment: С этим проблем нет, просто хочется получать, так сказать, готовое решение от браузера, раз уж элемент работает. Кстати, если вручную ввести значение с плюсом, то всё нормально, а вот когда в действие пускаются кнопки, тогда знак урезается. Может допилят, например, с помощью атрибута; если много желающих будет. Нужно написать в W3C :).

Comment: А ещё можно ввести несколько плюсов перед числом — пропускает.